# How to prevent SELinux errors from inside docker conainers

Tags: docker, selinux

I've run docker container like this:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
docker run -ti --rm --name test -v /home/kuba/tmp:/root/tmp ubuntu:14.04 bash
```

and after writing /root/tmp/file.txt file (inside docker container) I've got SELinux error:

```
Dodatkowe informacje:
Kontekst źródłowy             system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c444,c469
Kontekst docelowy             system_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
Obiekty docelowe              /root/tmp/file.txt [ file ]

(sorry for Polish labels)
```

Why SELinux go inside docker container, how to disable SELinux completely for docker? I've also had other SELinux errors that came from inside containers (was not able to run the app created from few docker containers). Is it possible to disable them all? I have permissive mode, so I've got only warnings, but I want to get rid of them, I would like to have warnings when something real happen.

**EDIT**:

This is the output of docker info:

```
$ docker info | grep -A4 'Security Options'
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
 selinux
Kernel Version: 5.2.9-100.fc29.x86_64
```

I don't know why I have the warning and I also don't know how to fix it.

Comment: do you run docker with `--selinux-enabled` flag? check with `docker info | grep 'Security Options'`

Comment: check also http://jaormx.github.io/2018/selinux-and-docker-notes/

Comment: @Bart Added the output for docker info, it seems that `--privileged` make the problem disappear.

Comment: @Bart removing `--selinux-enabled` from `/etc/sysconfig/docker` disabled selinux for docker.